# How to design hbase table

Tags: hbase

I am planning to design Hbase table for a JSON data.

As i am not much aware of Hbase concepts i would like to know what would be the best way to Design table for the JSON type mentioned below.

The Dotted line is the Logical Division in Json data : 
Which means A record has a rowkey which is uid, then there is request section in BOLD, response section in Italics & Classification. Under Classification there is an Array like structure.
I am thinking of creating 3 column families for 1 logical group each. But how to store the Array like structure ("Problem Reasons") into HBASE table. Does hbase any specific datatype apart from Binary ??

```
{
        "uid": "abc2342",
-----------------------------------

        "req1": sometext,
        "res1": sometext,
        "matter": "point1",
        "body": "point2",
-------------------------------------
        "response": null,
                "validity": null
---------------------------------------

    "classification": "Problems",
        "Problem reasons": [
            "Address Not found",
            "Invalid Phone Number",
            "Invalid Email"
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HBase is a dumb beast and you have to treat it as such. It's just a low level of indexed storage.

There is one rule that you should follow - your schema should be stored in a manner that it is access, not stored.
Based on other comments you should generate your rowkey using req1.

*But be warned! req1 must be well distributed, not a binary sequential value. Use a seed, if you have to.*

If you access your JSON object as a whole using the rowkey - then simply dumping everything into a binary string, BSON or some serializer is good enough for you. The number of updates doesn't really matter, if they are not concurrent.

If you want to be able to reference just a subset of data using a key or adding/changing values concurrently, then you should split them out.

---

Based on your example, you can easily split out the values into 3 column families:

1. Request (columns being like *req:req1*, *req:uid* and so on)
2. Response (columns being like *res:validity* and so on)
3. Classification

In the classification column family you could split out the values to the lowest level:

- A column cl:classification could identify the type of classification
- if your classification list is reasonable and finite, then you can name the column family by classification - column family *problem*
- then you can add array values as column values or column names:

  - problem:1 => "Address Not found"
  - problem:addressnotfound => 1 - the major benefit of this approach is that it can handle concurrent updates really well.
  - cl:reason1 => "Address Not found"

Comment: Thanks. This makes a lot of sense . But can u explain a little bit more on this "In the classification column family you could split out the values to the lowest level: " .. Here what exactly r u trying to say ..?? What should be the Column Family name and then what should be the columns within that Column Family. I am actually looking for that specific info

Comment: @AJm - I put out the two options which depend on the answer to one question - Is the list of possible problem reasons reasonably short?

If it's reasonably short and you could enumerate it, then you can have the it split out as: cl:type = "problem",  cl:address_not_found = 1,  cl:invalid_phone = 1, etc...

If your list if unbounded, then you can split it out by using indexes: cl:type = "problem", cl:r_1 = "Address Not found", cl:r_2 = "Invalid Email", etc...

Finally you can just have cl:type = "X", cl:values = "X\tY\tZ" (\t - yourdelimeter for array)

Answer (score 2):

HBase only has binary. You're going to have to serialize and deserialize the data yourself. The [HBase `Bytes`](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/Bytes.html) class can help you there (e.g. `Bytes.toBytes((short) 5)`). For the array, you're going to have to figure out what format works best for you considering how you plan on querying it. One simple way to store an array of strings is to join them with a separator that's not allowed in the string itself. You can also just dump it as JSON.

Another important consideration for your [schema is the key](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/rowkey.design.html). Usually you'd want to have a uniformly random key so you won't get hotspots that can reduce performance. A simple way to get that is to hash your string key and use the bytes of the hash.

For [column families](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/columnfamily.html):

> Physically, all column family members are stored together on the filesystem. Because tunings and storage specifications are done at the column family level, it is advised that all column family members have the same general access pattern and size characteristics.

IBM has a good [document](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPT3X_3.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.analyze.doc/doc/bigsql_designhints.html) with some rules of thumb:

> An HBase table is made of column families which are the logical and physical grouping of columns. The columns in one family are stored separately from the columns in another family. If you have data that is not often queried, assign that data to a separate column family.
>
> The column family and column qualifier names are repeated for each row. Therefore, keep the names as short as possible to reduce the amount of data that HBase stores and reads. For example, use f:q instead of mycolumnfamily:mycolumnqualifier.
>
> Because column families are stored in separate HFiles, keep the number of column families as small as possible. You also want to reduce the number of column families to reduce the frequency of MemStore flushes, and the frequency of compactions. And, by using the smallest number of column families possible, you can improve the LOAD time and reduce disk consumption.

Comment: This is just a theoretical answer Nothing practical

Comment: Please add more details about your data id, how you plan to query it and how you plan to insert it for a more specific answer.

Comment: Consider the above mentioned as my data. Now i wanted to know whether it is good to store it as Binary Table or Store the entire JSON into 1 column Family : column

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your structure is that each user has one request, one response, and several problems.

If so, just make UID the rowkey. Rowkey design is the most important part of HBase schema design. This is because HBase shards the data based on rowkey and it controls how you look up your data. To avoid hotspotting, you may want to prepend a hash of the UID to the front of the key. For example you could make your keys look like this `hash(UID):UID`  or  `f97h23:user123`.

Now on to your next question. HBase only stores bytes. It does not care what those bytes are. It's up to your program to know what the bytes you store mean. HBase doesn't know about data types with the exception of counters, but we will ignore those here.

This table seems fairly simple so I would make the rest of the JSON fields into a column each. For the array, I've done things like a delimited list within the column i.e. `Address Not found,Invalid Phone Number,Invalid Email`. Anytime you use a scheme like this be sure to either make the delimiting character illegal inside the data, or use an escaping scheme.

In most cases I think there is no reason for separate column families. It seems like you have a small amount of data per row, and you did not mention different access patterns, which makes me assume you mostly just get every field when you query for a UID. If this is truly the case, you could even have one column "JSON" that stores your json string above. The downside to doing this is the need to serialize and deserialize the JSON.

More information about your use-case would help guide the design.
Things like:

- Can you generally describe what problem you are solving with this database?
- Do you always read all columns, or just some?
- How many rows do you expect to have total?
- Do you usually append new records, or update existing records?
- What's the mix of reads to writes?
- What are the performance requirements?

Comment: Thanks Carlos. But i will give you more detail here. I will not search on the basis of uid. Search will be on the basis of assume 'req1'  and then we need to update the response section. The array in the JSON is dynamic it will get different number of elements and we might update that also. 
Also i did not understand that delimited List within column ... what are you trying to explain here..?
What i was thinking is to arrange the Columns in 3 logical groups so that they will have 3 CF and into that i will have my columns as shown above becoz if we update only that CF will be fetched

Comment: If you are searching based on "req1", then you likely want that in the rowkey. Are you searching both "req1" and "uid" or just "req1"? If just "req1", remove "uid" from the rowkey.  About the delimited idea, you could have columns like "error1", "error2", "error3", what I am suggesting is one column that contains "error1, error2, error3" and the errors are delimited by commas in this example.

Comment: Our rowkey will be generated i know u r suggesting req1 as rowkey for the speed we will get while searching. But can u please create a table with the structure given above and as per your design so that i will get an idea

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for. Both myself and the other answerer have described a specific table design. What specifically are you looking for?

Comment: Like create a table with the syntax u r suggesting